# I have used cv2.fullscreen and it works perfect but some details and quality is lost

Tags: python, opencv

there is lost of quality and both details when shown fullscreen using cv2.imshow

```
myimg = cv2.imread("image_for_bg.png",1)
nimg = np.array(myimg)
newImg = Image.fromarray(nimg)
img = cv2.cvtColor(nimg, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA)


cv2.namedWindow('My Window',cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.resizeWindow("My Window",1920,800)
cv2.setWindowProperty('My Window',cv2.WND_PROP_ASPECT_RATIO,cv2.WINDOW_KEEPRATIO)
cv2.setWindowProperty('My Window',cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN,cv2.WINDOW_FULLSCREEN)


cv2.imshow('My Window',myimg)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

this is displayed using code. all grooves are not present:

[image: 1]

this is the original image. all grooves are present:

[image: 2]

Comment: OpenCV's imshow, by default, stretches images using nearest neighbor sampling. this is known.

Comment: is there any way , by modifying the properties , acheive the goal of showing all grooves between tiles ? an answer will be greatly appreciated